# Lambda in a function

Tags: python

I am following the Python [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions).

```
def make_incrementor(n):
    return lambda x: x + n
```

Result:

```
f = make_incrementor(42)
print(f(1))
43
print(type(f))
<class 'function'>
```

Now consider we will replace the lambda expression by a regular function

```
def nolambda(x):
    return x

def make_incrementor(n):
    return nolambda(n)

f = make_incrementor(42)    
print(type(f))
<class 'int'>
```

In the first case it returned `<class 'function'>` but in the second it returned `<class 'int'>`

It only points to the lamba expression in the first case and do not execute it (ok, it would raise an error because of the missing argument). I could understand that but it returns an `int` rather than a `function` in the second example, so it is very strange to me. Could you explain what's going on?

Comment: Your two code samples aren't the same. `nolambda` just returns its argument, so when you return `nolambda(n)` you yet again return your argument.

Comment: Because you are returning a lambda, therefore a function

Comment: Like aplet said you are returning a function, which returns an intirger. func < func < int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, you are returning a *callable* (ie. the lambda function).

In the second example, you are ***calling*** the **`nolambda`** function, which means that the return value of **`make_incrementor`** will be the same value returned by **`nolambda`**.

To better understand, try looking at it like this:

```
def make_incrementor(n):
    def some_function(x):
        return x + n
    return some_function

def make_incrementor(n):
    some_return_value = nolambda(n)
    return some_return_value
```

Answer (score 2):

In this code, the lambda function "sees" the argument `x` and the variable `n`, which is in the lambda's closure:

```
def make_incrementor(n):
    return lambda x: x + n
```

In the other example, you have made three differences, which cause different behaviour:

- you placed the function `nolambda` outside the `make_incrementor` function, so it does not have the closure
- in the first example, you return the function itself (i.e. the lambda, which is a function), and in the second you return the result of `nolambda`
- the `lambda` returns `x + n`, whereas the `nolambda` returns just `x`

The following would be equivalent to the example with lambda:

```
def make_incrementor(n):

    def nolambda(x):
        return x + n

    return nolambda
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, where you return `lambda x: x + n`, you're returning a `callable` (i.e. anonymous function) without an invocation – the callable maps the input parameter, `n`, to the `lambda` function but does not actually get invoked. In the second, you are returning the invoked function, because you're actually calling it by using parentheses within the `make_incrementor` function's body.